# onTabReselected for actionbar tab getting called when unwanted

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I followed instruction for actionbar Tab from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

I'd like to user to be able to scroll back to top of list-view when they reselect a tab.

I put `listView.setSelection(0)` inside onTabReselected(Tab,FragmentTransaction) method.
It works as intended when I re-click the tab already chosen.

But the function is also called when I didn't expect it to be.
I start a new activity.
When I come back to the original activity(with the tab), the onTabReselected function is called.

How can I differentiate the two cases so that I don't scroll the list when coming back from another activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected call to onTabReselected was due to my `setSelectedNavigationItem` call in onResume.

problem solved.